# best way to relate a variable and its ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am getting results from a database with a simple php while loop, one of the pieces of information is a number that links to another table where the value is stored, I can think of plenty of ways to get this information linked and display the text related to the value but I want to know the *fastest* way to do it as I have a huge set of results so every bit of speed will make a difference. Is an array fastest, javascript? any advice you can give me would be great.

The schema would look something like this

```
col_table 
colID(autonumber) colName(str) colState(int) colDate(date) 

state_table
stateID(int) stateType(str)
```

I want to select the correct state type based on the colState matching a stateID and output the stateType while preserving the stateID for so I can edit the field and update the database using the number.

Comment: Without seeing your code there isn't a great deal of guidance to be given.

Comment: why don't you `JOIN` the tables?

Comment: The fastest way to do it, is to write it the first way that comes into your head.  The computer is faster than any algorithm you could come up with.

Comment: Okay, I feel like I have overcomplicated the objective a bit in my head. Writing down exactly what I was trying to do made me see I had gone off on a wild tangent to where I should be going

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MySQL will be faster.
If you have to get through a PHP loop to read your results and make each time a new MySQL request, your script will take longer.

You can increase speed on MySQL by creating the right kind/amount of index, choosing wisely what is store in each field.

The later you parse content, the longer it will take. If you go for js, you will have to read a DB, loop trough it in PHP and do it again in JS, and making more request again ...

A join can be a good solution. A view can be even more easier to treat. Yuo can also consider caching results

Answer (score 1):

Use a timer in php and try trial and error method. Use the time returned by the timer to evaluate speed and efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

you should prepare your data on server side it is faster.

Whether you choose your server or database with a fast query it depends. If you have complex object graphs then the processing of results from db  in order to create associations would be time consuming so an ORM is the way to go, otherwise as is your case with a simple join i would simply retrieve all data from db.

If you use php for rendering as well then render it using php no js.

If you use js for your ui then prepare data on server side and publish it via a REST webservice in json,i.e. usind json_encode functions of php, then retrieve it from js and output.